# Global variable declaration from class module

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with multiple modules and multiple subs. There are some variables though that are usesd constantly in most subs such as given worksheest.

eg

```
dim cr as worksheet
set cr=sheets("combined_report")
```

I have this written in way too many subs. Can I write this once in say a class module and use "cr" from any sub in any module without having to reassign it?

Comment: You don't need a class module; but you will need to have an `extern` declaration at the top of every module that wants to use this (and you need to make sure that the code that makes this assignment is used before you use it elsewhere).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can!

Generally, you can define a global variable in any module before the declaration of your subs/functions using the `Global` keyword, e.g.

```
Option Explicit

Global cr as Worksheet

Public Sub mySub...
```

The global variable will keep it's scope - but of course you have to initialize is first, i.e. assign a value/object to it.

It is best practice to prefix global variable with a `g`, e.g. `gWSMain`, so you'll always know you're dealing with a global variable.

In case you only want a global variable for one or more specific worksheets in your workbook, you don't need a global variable at all! Instead, you can access them directly with their code names. Those are usually `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc. - but you can change the name in the properties window.

These worksheets are available globally in your application, the same way as `ThisWorkbook` is.

Comment: so i have to have this at the top of each module?

Comment: + 1  for the alternative :)

Comment: @user2385809: no, you only need this once in one module.

Comment: @user2385809: but even better, simply rename the `SheetX` in the VB editor to `CR` and you can access it from anywhere with out initialization.

Comment: also i still must   set cr = ...  in every sub. any ways of doing this once and for all? how about declaring the global var in ThisWorkbook and setting it there too?

Comment: the problem is the names are too long (for other users to understand) and its very annoying writing "Sheets("combined_report")  over and over and over

Comment: I usually have a "subInit" that I call from any entry point routine anyway. This not only initializes any global vars, but also sets `Application.ScreenUpdate=False` as well as `.EnableEvents`, `.Calculation`, ...

Comment: Interesting apprach. Ya that makes sense; i will do that. Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind you're going to need to be careful to ensure the use of `cr` is initialized every time you use it.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with a function in a standard module and cache the reference using the `Static` keyword:

```
Function CR() As Worksheet
    Static CRSheet As Worksheet
    If CRSheet Is Nothing Then Set CRSheet = Sheets("combined_report")
    Set CR = CRSheet
End Function
```

Comment: This is a good solution. You end up with the overhead of the function call, but it guarantees that the value is valid when you need it.